# where can i find the form data in the inspect element?

Tags: express, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I'm no longer seeing posted form data in Chrome Inspector, Network tab

I see sections of General, Response Headers and Request Headers, but no Form Data

Obviously I am looking at a POST, and the server is receiving and updating the data.

The only thing that has changed is the addition of the Vue developer extension.

Anyone any ideas?

i was expecting to see the form data

Comment: Is the Payload tab still there? Or try remove the extension and see if the error still occurs